# Numpy: Convert array of keys into array of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have an array and a dict having the entries of array as keys. How can I get array with entries having values corresponding to keys in the first array? What is the pythonic way without using simple loops.

For e.g. 
I have an array:

```
 a = np.array([['1','2','3'],['10','4','5'],['9','34','6']],dtype=np.object)

[['1' '2' '3']
 ['10' '4' '5']
 ['9' '34' '6']]
```

and dict:

```
d = {'1':23,'2':13,'3':3,'4':43,'5':230,'6':893,'7':98,'8':665,'9':33,'10':8797}
```

I want to get the array(for keys(for e.g. '34') not in dict, I should have 0) :

```
 b = np.array([[23,13,3],[8797,43,230],[33,0,893]])

[[  23   13    3]
 [8797   43  230]
 [  33    0  893]]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK found the answer:

```
a_flat = numpy.ndarray.flatten(a)
b = [d[x] if d.has_key(x) else 0 for x in a_flat]
b = numpy.reshape(c,a.shape)
print b
```